# Convert a string to a dictionary using regex-grouping

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, regex-group

I have a number of txt files in a format like this -

```
\n==== Intro \n text \n text \n==== Body \n text \n text \n==== Refs \n test \n text
```

I'd like to get these into a dictionary that looks like this -

```
{'Intro': '\n text \n text \n', 
'Body': '\n text \n text', 
'Refs': '\n test \n text'}
```

I'm concerned about the time it is going to take to process all of the txt files so wanted an approach that would take as little time as possible and I don't care about splitting the text into lines.

I am trying to use regex, but am struggling to get it to work correctly - I think my last regex group is incorrect. Below is what I currently have. Any suggestions would be great.

```
pattern = r"(====.)(.+?\b)(.*)"
matches = re.findall(pattern, data, re.DOTALL) 
my_dict = {b:c for a,b,c in matches}
```

Comment: Does it need regex?

Comment: There are certainly other approaches. I thought regex would be the quickest, but won't use it if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with the `split()` command [intro](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) , but you can work step by step, splitting on `split("====")` first and then further as needed.

Comment: Are the text files small enough to be completely in-memory (per-file), or do you need to process it as a stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
d = dict(re.findall('(?<=\n====\s)(\w+)(\s+[^=]+)', text, re.M | re.DOTALL))
print(d)
{'Body': ' \n text \n text \n',
 'Intro': ' \n text \n text \n',
 'Refs': ' \n test \n text'}
```

---

**Regex Details**

```
(?<=    # lookbehind (must be fixed width)
    \n      # newline
    ====    # four '=' chars in succession
    \s      # single wsp character
)
(       # first capture group
    \w+     # 1 or more alphabets (or underscore)    
)    
(       # second capture group
    \s+     # one or more wsp characters
    [^=]+   # match any char that is not an '='
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need RegEx here, instead you can use classic `split()` function.

Here, I use `textwrap` for readability:

```
import textwrap

text = textwrap.dedent("""\

==== Intro 
 text 
 text 
==== Body 
 text 
 text 
==== Refs 
 test 
 text""")
```

You can do:

```
result = {}
for part in text.split("==== "):
    if not part.isspace():
        section, content = part.split(' ', 1)
        result[section] = content
```

Or initialise a `dict` with a list of tuples in comprehension:

```
result = dict(part.split(' ', 1)
              for part in text.split("==== ")
              if not part.isspace())
```

Comment: This hardcodes a lot of things and is dependent on the existence of characters in certain positions to work.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Yes, I know. But without context, it's difficult to improve. The OP asked a weird question, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

s = "\n==== Intro \n text \n text \n==== Body \n text \n text \n==== Refs \n test \n text"

final_data = re.findall("(?<=\n\=\=\=\=\s)[a-zA-Z]+\s", s)
text = re.findall("\n .*? \n .*?$|\n .*? \n .*? \n", s)
final_body = {a:b for a, b in zip(final_data, text)}
```

Output:

```
{'Body ': '\n text \n text \n', 'Intro ': '\n text \n text \n', 'Refs ': '\n test \n text'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to read the whole file into memory, you can process it line-by-line like this:

```
marker = "==== "
def read_my_custom_format(file):
    current_header = None
    current_contents = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() # trim whitespace, including trailing newline
        if line.startswith(marker):
            yield current_header, current_contents # emit current section
            current_header = line[len(marker):] # trim marker
            current_contents = []
        else:
            current_contents.append(line)
```

This is a generator yielding tuples instead of building a dictionary.
This way it only holds one section at a time in memory.
Also, each key maps to a list of lines instead of one string, but you could easily just `"".join(iterable)` them.
If you want to produce a single dictionary, which again takes memory proportional to the input file, you can just do it like this:

```
with open("your_textfile.txt") as file:
    data = dict(read_my_custom_format(file))
```

Because `dict()` can take an iterable of 2-tuples